# getting quize data, questions and answers in 1 query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to get quize title, quize description, quize questions and answers for each questions. My table structure is:

```
quizes
quize_id | title | user_id | ...

questions
questions_id | quize_id | question | ...

question_answers
answer_id | question_id | user_id | answer | ...
```

I can use join

```
SELECT * FROM quizes JOIN questions q ON q.quize_id=quizes.quize_id JOIN question_answers a ON a.question_id=q.question_id
```

But the problem with this is that I will get in results many rows with redundant data. For example each row will carry field title,user_id, ... Another way is to make for each question extra query to get answers. Is there any better way? Should I use only 1 query or more?

Comment: Not sure I understand the part *for each question extra query to get answers*

Comment: For each question new query just to get anwers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found also another way which return all data I need, including user details for each question:

```
SELECT 
    question, 
    group_concat(qa.answer SEPARATOR ',') as answers,
    group_concat(qa.user_id SEPARATOR ',') as userIds,
    group_concat(up.nickname SEPARATOR ',') as nickname
FROM quize_questions qq
INNER JOIN question_answers qa ON qa.question_id=qq.question_id
INNER JOIN user_profile up ON up.user_id = qa.user_Id
GROUP BY qq.question_id
```

I am just not sure if this is the right way. I am worried about speed.

Comment: Since there is no subquery, performance should not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your tables hold 3 types of data. If you use the query you've got, you'll get all the data as a big table. You've said that this involves a lot of duplication.

If you use multiple queries, you will get multiple result sets, which effectively will leave you with multiple tables, and thus this is unlikely to help.

You could cut the query down to just the columns you want to get the data for:

```
SELECT qq.Question, qa.Answer
FROM quizes qz 
  join questions qq on qz.quize_id = qq.quize_id 
  join question_answers qa on qq.question_id = qa.question_id
WHERE qz.quize_id = @quize_id
ORDER BY 1, 2  --or other ordering
```

However where there are multiple answers for the same question, the question will be repeated on every row. There isnt much you can do about that, it is the price of combining multiple table's data into one table ("denormalising").

If you need to format your output table so that it looks like this (but with more columns):

```
    Quize_id | Question | Answer
    1          Q1         A1
                          A2
               Q2         A3
    2          Q3         A4
```

This is a whole different matter. You would need to use the query you've got to populate a temporary table, ordering the data by the sort order you want displayed. To this table you'd need to add a primary key (integer) column, then run a set of update statements to replace the repeated values with nulls, then output the table in the order of the primary key column. (There are other ways to do this, but this is the easiest to explain)

Does this help?

Comment: It helps. So in general when speaking about performance it is better to use join and get big table with a lot of duplication than using multiple quries?